# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed sqlite python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Hi i have this sql error that just appeared (before worked fine) , i'm so boggled by it i don't find any viable adjustment.
i share below the schema of the data frame and the code
if someone can help im grateful

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
username TEXT NOT NULL,
hash TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);

CREATE TABLE comments(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
comment TEXT NOT NULL,
url TEXT NOT NULL,
data DATETIME NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id));

CREATE TABLE video(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
video_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
data DATETIME NOT NULL,
url TEXT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id));

CREATE TABLE video_comment(
video_id INTEGER,
comment_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(video_id) REFERENCES video(id),
FOREIGN KEY(comment_id) REFERENCES comments(id));
```

code :

```py
            for elemen in comments:
                print(elemen.text)
                db.execute("INSERT INTO comments (user_id, comment,data,url) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 1, elemen.text,current_time, url)
                comment_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM comments WHERE comment = ?", elemen.text)[0]
                print(comment_id)
                print(comment_id['id'])

#error appear now 
                db.execute("INSERT INTO video_comment (video_id,comment_id) VALUES (1,?)", int(comment_id['id']))

            db.execute("INSERT INTO video (user_id,video_id,data,url) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 1,1, current_time, url)
```

comments is a list of comments.
the error appear after the two print (), the code can put the comment in the database and after crash.

thanks!!

if i use the terminal with sqlite3 the same query  works fine , so i don understand.

ERROR =

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/pietrocaracristi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject-1-12/final-project/main.py", line 184, in scrape_comments
    db.execute("INSERT INTO video_comment (video_id,comment_id) VALUES (1,?)", int(comment_id['id']))
  File "/Users/pietrocaracristi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject-1-12/final-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 29, in decorator
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pietrocaracristi/PycharmProjects/pythonProject-1-12/final-project/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cs50/sql.py", line 405, in execute
    raise e
ValueError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

Comment: Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: The inserted values must be tuple, like (1,1, current_time, url). Try to add the brackets.

Comment: I used OCR to put your schema into your post as text; it seems correct, but you'll have to double check.

Comment: What is db in  db.execute? The cursor? Not clear, also the error message is missing.

Comment: i tried with the bracket but same error, i was thinking if is it possible that the multithreading cause some error, because i use the multithreading to do this process ( the comments are from one video , but there are multiple video ).

Comment: find the error, the problem was that my data frame i this table 
CREATE TABLE video_comment(
video_id INTEGER,
comment_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(video_id) REFERENCES video(id),
FOREIGN KEY(comment_id) REFERENCES comments(id));
in video_id is connected to video(id) , and i was using 1 in the code meanwhile it wasn't present in my database.
now works

Answer (score 0):

The `video_comment` table has a foreign key referencing the `video` table. That means to insert a row into `video_comment`, the `video` must already exist first.

You should swap the order of your INSERT statements so that the corresponding `video` and `comment` rows are inserted before the `video_comment` rows.

```
# I moved this line to insert the video before the video_comment:
db.execute("INSERT INTO video (user_id,video_id,data,url) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 1,1, current_time, url)

for elemen in comments:
    print(elemen.text)
    db.execute("INSERT INTO comments (user_id, comment,data,url) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", 1, elemen.text,current_time, url)
    comment_id = db.execute("SELECT id FROM comments WHERE comment = ?", elemen.text)[0]
    print(comment_id)
    print(comment_id['id'])

    db.execute("INSERT INTO video_comment (video_id,comment_id) VALUES (1,?)", int(comment_id['id']))
```

This will prevent the "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" error.

---

Some other suggestions to improve your code:

- Consider enclosing all of these inserts in a transaction
- If each comment can be linked to exactly one video, a better schema might be to have a `video_id` column in the `comment` table, and to remove the `video_comment` table. Your current schema technically allows a comment to be linked to multiple videos, which is probably not what you want.